# Jquery validator module and function call after success

Tags: javascript, jquery

First I don't have much experience with javascript and jquery :) I am just trying to find a quick way to connect jquery email validator module with a function that checks recaptcha. Here is my code:

```
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
debug: true,
success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
rules: {
field: {
required: true,
email: true
 }
}
});
```

Works fine! Inputs are validated.

Now after validation I need two things: First I need to call recapVerify(), after recaptcha gets validated I need to submit my form. This is the example I use: [email method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/). I know I need to use submitHandler now but I can't figure out where and how?

Btw. this is recapVerify() function that I want to use:

```
 function recapVerify(){
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'captcha_check.php',
    data: {
        recaptcha_challenge_field:$('#recaptcha_challenge_field').val(),
        recaptcha_response_field:$('#recaptcha_response_field').val()
    }
}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    if (data == 'success'){
        $('#err').addClass('hidden');
        //document.forms[0].submit(); // uncomment this line to submit your form
        alert('Success, the form and reCAPTCHA validated, your form was submitted');
    } else {
        $('#err').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
        console.log('recaptcha or service failure');
});
}
```

Comment: Any js error is coming.?

Comment: I don't see any error in browser, however if I add `success: recapVerify();` instead of `success: document.forms[0].submit()` the jquery validation module will not work?? I mean it will pass to action script without prior check of field input?

Comment: Try using `submitHandler : recaptchaVerify()` instead of `success : recaptchaVerify()`. according to the docs at http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/  `success` is used to indicate valid inputs.

Comment: `submitHandler: recapVerify();` same thing validation module stops working! Here is code that I use: [code](http://pastebin.com/aqWksAHf)

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan well that is what I need, I need to check if inputs for email field are valid at first. Once that is validated I want to check if recaptchat input is valid.

Comment: @mrki submitHandler will be called only if the inputs are valid.

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan Ok, but it doesn't work for me like that if I remove `success: "valid"` and add `submitHandler: recapVerify();` instead the form will be submitted even with empty email field?

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan Can you let me know where exactly do I need to use `submitHandler` in above code to submit my form after it has been validated?

Answer (score 1):

use submitHandler on your jquery validate function. Debug is not needed. In essence this is the javascript you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test-form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
           }
        },
            submitHandler : recaptchaVerify
    });
});

function recaptchaVerify(form){
    console.log(form);
    alert("in submit handler");
}
```

According to the documents at jQuery validate

> submitHandler (default: native form submit)
>
> Type: Function()
>
> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form
>   as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to
>   submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

Have also created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL6h2Lfm/) so that you can use it.

Comment: Did you try? I already did and it doesn't work? The validation will not work in this case and form will be submitted before the input gets validated :(

Comment: @ Arvind Sridharan Yes I just did again, it will not validate email field it will call recaptchaVerify without validation.

Comment: the example i have shown validates the email. please see the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/sL6h2Lfm/

Comment: You are right about that, I didn't notice wrong ID in form tag and submit tag. Your example works! Though after validation it gets into recaptchaVerify function but the function isn't executed, any idea why? Here is code: [link](http://pastebin.com/i1Dga1P8)

Comment: @mrki - you have two recaptchaVerify functions. delete the one at line 63 and try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60166/discussion-between-mrki-and-arvind-sridharan).